# Why does the word 'typedef' need 'typename' after it for dependent types?

Tags: c++, typedef, typename

Dependent types generally need `typename` to tell the compiler the member is a type, not a function or variable.

However, this is *not* always the case.
For example, a base class doesn't require this, because it can only ever be a type:

```
template<class T> struct identity { typedef T type; }
template<class T> class Vector : identity<vector<T> >::type { };  // no typename
```

Now my question is, **why does `typedef` ever require `typename` after it**?

```
template<class T> class Vector
{
    typedef typename /* <-- why do we need this? */ vector<T>::iterator iterator;
};
```

Comment: Why not ask the same question about e.g. `static`?

Comment: @n.m.: Ooh sorry I got it now. Yeah I didn't think of that, although I think it might be because of implicitly-int-by-default... so `static x;` would be `int` by default wouldn't it? (Or at least it would in C?) But honestly not sure, that's a good question.

Comment: C has dropped implicit int about 15 years ago too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typedef` does not need to appear before the type.

```
template <typename T>
struct S { typedef T type; };
template <typename T>
void f() { typename S<T>::type typedef t; }
```

This is perfectly valid, and in this case, I hope you can understand that parsing would be complicated if `typename` were optional.

I can understand that

```
template <typename T>
void f() { typedef S<T>::type t; }
```

*could* be interpreted differently, but that would introduce unexpected cases where the position of the `typedef` keyword suddenly becomes significant.

Comment: Sure, but no one said it should be optional when the `typedef` comes later, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad I quote from your question: "Now my question is, why does typedef ever require typename?"

Comment: You should read the title, "Why does the word `typedef` need `typename` **after it** for dependent types"? If that's not the question you're answering then it's not really answering my question...

Comment: @Mehrdad In that case, perhaps because it would be worse to make it depend on the position of the `typedef` keyword?

Comment: Fair enough, +1, though not terribly convincing. I changed my question as well just to make that clear.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks, and I edited my answer to make it clearer. I doubt I will be able to come up with a more convincing example, though, sorry.

Comment: Well if there's no more convincing example then this is clearly the best :) I'll wait a bit to see if someone can come up with a better reason but otherwise this is probably the answer, thanks.

Comment: How could `typedef S<T>::type t;` be interpreted differently? `S<T>::type` can only be a type here for the expression to be valid

Comment: @bolov "differently" from the current situation (and the situation where `typedef` appears later), where `S<T>::type` is treated as a variable and thus an error unless the `typename` keyword is used.

Comment: I guess the point is since it is inside the `typedef` it is only valid to be treated as a type, not as a variable.

Comment: @bolov Did you see the first part of my answer? `S<T>::type typedef t;` would be very complicated for a compiler, since `S<T>::type` would first be parsed, determined to be a variable, and then, when `typedef` is seen, the whole declaration needs to be re-parsed.

Comment: yes I saw and I understand, but I was talking about the specific case when `typedef` is the first keyword in the expression.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the right answer. The position of `typedef` in the grammar is variable – it can appear before and after the type name. Of course the grammar *could* introduce an extra clause which states that *if* it appears before the type name, no `typename` is required. But that would make the grammar even *more* complex. Requiring `typename` indiscriminately makes parsing much (!) easier.

Comment: @bolov And by the time you commented, I had already expanded my answer to say "for consistency". :)