# Using own class name to resolve type in a deduced context

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43781269/2378300) question using a C++ construction that I'm not familiar with. I want to know if this is legal or allowed by both g++ (6.3.0) and clang++ (3.5.0) by mistake. The example is available [online](http://ideone.com/qFXwGz):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    using Type = int;
};

template <typename T>
struct intermediate : Base<T>
{
    // 'Type' is not defined here, which is fine
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : intermediate<T>
{
    using Type = typename Derived<T>::Type; // Is this legal?
//    using Type = typename intermediate<T>::Type; // Normal way of doing it
};

int main()
{
    Derived<void>::Type b = 1;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments (by [underscore_d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2757035/underscore-d)) `<T>` is not required in the `Derived` class. That is, this is perfectly fine:

```
using Type = typename Derived::Type;
```

Comment: Yes, this is legal, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name under "unknown specializations".

Comment: It seems that the template argument `<T>` is not required, and we can simply write `using Type = typename Derived::Type;` where `Derived` always refers to the current class type 'as if' with template arguments. Am I missing something? I remember using this pattern before and not having to specify the template arguments. Is this well-defined too?

Comment: @underscore_d You are of course right, I suppose its a left over from `intermediate<T>...`. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me a while to understand the (very good) question, so let me first explain how I understoud the point:

At template level, a base class template's scope is not examined if this base class template depends on a template-parameter (cf, for example, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643190/2630032)).
 Hence, a type declared by `using Type = int` in a class template with template parameter like `template <typename T> struct Base` will not be visible to a class deriving from this base class template like `template <typename T> struct intermediate :  Base<T>`, unless one uses a qualified name, i.e. `typename Base<T>::Type`).

At class level, in contrast, such a type declaration would be visible even when used without qualified name. So when instantiating above mentioned template class, a type name that was "invisible" at template level will become visible at the level of the insantiated classes.

So if the subclass at template level would define a type with the same (unqualified) name as the base class template, this would not be apparent at template level.
 But might such a situation lead to a (probably mismatching) redefinition of a type when instantiating the template, since then both type definitions based on unqualified type names might become visible under the same name?

As pointed out by n.m., who provied [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) in his comment, type definition sticks to the view at the point of template definition, even if at instance level a different type would be resolved:

> Non-dependent names are looked up and bound at the point of template
>   definition. This binding holds even if at the point of template
>   instantiation there is a better match.

Thus, it is actually legal, as this will not lead to an invalid redefinition of a type.

However, as the subclass' type definition is actually considered as a new type, it may even be defined in a different manner, which is probably not intended:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
    using Type = int;
};

template <typename T>
struct intermediate : Base<T>
{
    // 'Type' is not defined here, which is fine
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : intermediate<T>
{
    //using Type = typename Derived<T>::Type; // legal.
    using Type = const char*; // Legal, too!
};

int main()
{
    Derived<void>::Type b = "OK, but is this actually intended?";
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

So the subclass does not "inherit" but "cover" the respective type. 
If one wants to "inherit", one should write:

```
struct Derived : intermediate<T>
{
    using typename intermediate<T>::Type; // Inherits the type.
};
```